# Getting printf to print escaped backslashes

Tags: bash, shell

Because I need to be able to print lines that may start with what would otherwise be treated as an option by `echo`, I devised a shell function that uses `printf` to print to the terminal. If I needed to print newlines or tabs, I learned that I have to use `%b` instead of `%s` because `printf "%s" "\n"` would print the literal `\n` to the screen. The function is defined as this:

```
my_echo () {
    printf "%b" "${1}"
}
```

Just recently, I found out that trying to print escaped escape sequences is more complicated than it normally is. The command `printf "%b" "\\n"` will print a newline. To print the literal for a newline, I have to use `printf "%b" "\\\n"`, but using this requires recoding all of my other functions and scripts to handle this. Is there some way to get `printf "%b" "\\n"` or whatever to come out as the escaped escape sequence?

Comment: The ideal approach is to put your escape sequences into your format string, and keep them out of your data. `printf '%s\n' "This prints one line"` -- otherwise, you'll have a very bad time of it when you're trying to echo values that contain literal backslashes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Escape sequences need to be in the data.

Comment: Mixing escape sequences and data is a **horrible** idea. The interpreter has no way of knowing which of those escape sequences were intended by the developer to be interpreted, and which come from data intended for literal display.

Comment: @Melab - Why do they "need" to be in the data? Perhaps if you provided more context for this, we'd be able to clearly identify it as an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), and help you find a "better way".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's silly. The whole point of this shell function is to be able to print any character. Python, when it opens a file and reads, represents characters, like newlines, with the exact same sequence that would be used in a script's non-data strings (e.g., `\n`).

Comment: @ghoti I wrote this function because option handling is a pain in the ass when I need `echo` to be able to print any kind of string, including ones like `-n` or `-e`. Another thing is that I've written another function that uses a combination of `tr` and `sed` to escape special characters (e.g., change `\n` (a newline) to `\\n`). `sed` can't be used to replace newlines and I've run into trouble with my escape function turning something like `\\n` into `\\\\n` (it gets returned as either `\\n` or `\n`).

Comment: @Melab, with respect to your discussion of Python -- other than using Pascal strings rather than C strings (and thus being able to represent NUL), Python and bash do the exact same thing under the hood: Both store underlying data as a literal string of bytes (ignoring Unicode, which is a longer discussion). Display with escape sequences is a matter of external representation, not internal storage -- if you *want* bash to provide an equivalent to Python's `repr()` for strings. it's perfectly capable of doing that: `printf 's=%q\n' "$s"`

Comment: @Melab, ...anyhow, there's nothing wrong with your function, except that you're misunderstanding how backslashes work inside double quotes when forming the strings you pass to it. **Your function isn't wrong; rather, the strings you pass to it are wrong because they're interpreted in a manner you don't intend at the time they're parsed, because of the inappropriate selection of double quotes to contain them**.

Comment: (I'm also... really confused with your terminology. A literal newline is, well, a newline. `\n` is an escape sequence for a newline, **not** a literal newline.

Comment: @Melab, ...so, let's go back to Python here. When you tell the Python interpreter to print a string and it represents a tab with `\t`, that's not because it actually put a `\t` in that string; it's because it's running `repr()` to decide how to interpret the string when it's displaying it to you.

Comment: @Melab, ...so, if you `print(stringvar)` in Python, it's going to print a literal tab if the string had one originally not because it's interpreting a `\t` sequence back into a tab, but because the contents of the string **already is a tab in the first place**.

Comment: @Melab, ...so, the bash equivalent to Python's `s='hello\tworld'` is `s=$'hello\tworld'` -- in both cases you're creating a string which contains a **literal** tab, where indexing to the sixth character in that string will emit a tab, not a backslash (as it will with the bash `s='hello\tworld'` or `s="hello\\tworld"` approaches you're trying here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When interacting with Python via a script, that is true. It is not true when Python is being used in interactive mode.

Comment: @Melab, it's still true in interactive mode -- the only thing that's different is that you have a REPL that automatically prints `repr()` output. Just because the output from `repr(_)` is being printed doesn't mean that the internal storage is anything other than the literal text.

Comment: @Melab, ...and as I pointed out before, you can prove this **trivially**. Run `'\\'[0] in 'foo\tbar'`, and you get false, not true -- because what the string *actually contains* is a tab literal, not a two-character syntax starting with a backslash and then a `t`.

Comment: @Melab, ...similarly, at a bash shell, if you run `s=$'foo\tbar'; printf '<%s>\n' "${s:3:1}"` you print a tab, whereas if you run `s='foo\tbar'; printf '<%s>\n' "${s:3:1}"` you print a backslash. The first syntax is identical to what Python does with `s='foo\tbar'; print '<%s>' % (s[3],)`; the second one is equivalent to `s=r'foo\tbar'; print '<%s>' % (s[3],)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Then what about when I use `print("\t")`? Is that a tab as well?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand that `\t` is internally represented as a tab.

Comment: Yes, `print("\t")` in Python is passing a one-character string with a literal tab to `print`, just as `printf '<%s>\n' $'\t'` passes a one-character string to `printf` as the final argument, but *unlike* `printf '<%b>\n' '\t'` passing a two-character string in that same position. My understanding is that we're now in agreement on the above -- is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

#### Answer: Literal

Quoting types matter. If you don't want backslashes to be interpreted *before* they get to your function, put them in single-quoted strings:

```
printf '%b' '\\n'
```

...prints, as you request, a single backslash followed by a `n`, with no trailing newline.

---

#### Answer: Best-Practice

Keep your escape sequences in your format strings, and out of your data. Thus:

```
my_echo() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
my_echo_n() { printf '%s' "$*"; }
```

is actually a closer equivalent to standard `echo` behavior: Printing only a newline can be done by just calling `my_echo` with no arguments; printing a literal can also be done by *passing* that literal around: `my_echo_n $'\n'` will print a literal newline without any `%b` involved.

Similarly, to include a literal tab:

```
my_echo $'hello\tworld'
```

or

```
my_echo "hello"$'\t'"world"
```

Comment: Putting the escape sequences in the formatting defeats the whole purpose of the function. The data must be able to contain escape sequences because it needs to be able to print anything, such as backslashes, tabs, and newlines.

Comment: You can do that even with `%s`, by passing **literal** backslashes, tabs, or newlines instead of escape sequences for them. I demonstrate exactly that in the last paragraph of the answer, but can extend same if it was sufficiently unclear.

Comment: @Melab, ...moreover, the first section of this answer *does* tell you how to get your desired effect (by using single quotes rather than double).

Comment: `printf "%s" "\n"` writes the literal `\n` to the terminal instead of a newline. `%b` is required to get the `\n` interpreted as a newline.

Comment: Shells do not perform substitution inside single quotes. Also, there is no way to escape a single quote inside single quotes (at least with bash).

Comment: @Melab, you can use more than one quoting type for a single string literal. And in bash, `$'\''` works perfectly well.

Comment: @Melab, ...to demonstrate the other: `"$foo"$'\t'"$bar"` gives you your expansion of `$foo`, your literal tab, and then an expansion of `$bar`.

Comment: `printf '%s'  '\b'` was what I was desperately searching for for my function.